# Oracle HCM API endpoints

Tags: rest

We are trying to extract Questions (feedback requested) and Answers (feedback provided) from Oracle HCM REST API, I can get question through:

https://DOMAIN/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/questionnaires

and then individual questions through:
https://DOMAIN/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/questionnaires/{questionnairesUniqID}

Any idea how do I get the answers/feedback that we received for these questionnaires

I have also tried: /hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/givenFeedbacks but it returns "404 Not found"